# Why isn't operator* for unique_ptr noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, c++14, noexcept

In C++11 and draft C++14, the dereferencing operators (`operator*` and `operator->`) for `shared_ptr` are both `noexcept`. But for `unique_ptr`, `operator->` is `noexcept`, but `operator*` isn't. Why isn't `operator*` for `unique_ptr` `noexcept` (or, alternatively, why is `operator*` for `shared_ptr` `noexcept`)?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203541/why-does-stdunique-ptr-operator-throw-and-operator-does-not-throw

Comment: @milleniumbug it is indeed a duplicate.